# Getting keyboard input details

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a textbox on which a `keyup` eventlistener is attached which is a JavaScript function, say `exec()`. Now the `exec()` method should not get called if some keys are pressed such as:

```
ctrl+ anything,
shift+anything,
alt+ anything.
```

Can someone guide me how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check some of the properties of the events.

```
textbox.onkeyup = function (e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.shiftKey || e.metaKey) return;
  exec();
}
```

Comment: it says ctrlKey is null or not an object in IE.

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing it as `e.ctrlKey` and not just `ctrlKey`? I don't think this error can be triggered by `e.ctrlKey`.

Comment: Yes even I am doing it in Netbeans IDE where I got suggestion when i pressed ctrl+space. The above error in IE means the object called 'e' donot have any property named 'ctrlKey'. Kindly help.